# songs getting mixed up in listview

Tags: android

i want to get the list of all the music files in android device so i used the following code

```
public class MusicAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;
        private LayoutInflater l_Inflater;

        public MusicAdapter(Context c) {
              mContext = c;
              l_Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
        }

        public int getCount() {
              return count;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
              return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
              return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
              System.gc();

            TextView tv = new TextView(mContext.getApplicationContext());
            String id = null;
            TextView txt_itemName = null;

            if (convertView == null) {



convertView = l_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, null);
            txt_itemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            ImageView itemImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);    





                music_column_index = musiccursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
            musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);
            id = musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);


            txt_itemName.setText(id);



            } else  {}




            return convertView;


        }
  }
```

everything works fine But when I scroll up and down, the list is mixed up. I tap on an title but it plays the wrong one. Each time I go back to the top of the list, a different song is displayed as the first song. what do i do.. ?? how do i solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what is wrong:

```
    public Object getItem(int position) {
          return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
          return position;
    }
```

In `getItem` you need to return an instance that represents your object, maybe something like a `Music` object. And in the `getItemId` you need return an unique value for that instance.

Let's pretend that you load an array with `Music` instances, something like this:

```
public class MusicAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public class Music {
        private Long id;
        private String pathToSd;
        private Long lenght;
    }

    private List<Music> mMusicList;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public MusicAdapter(Context context, List<Music> music) {
        mMusicList = music;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mMusicList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mMusicList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return mMusicList.get(position).id; //If you aren't saving your list of music in some place like a db
                                        //and thus, you don't have an id, you can return -1.
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertedView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertedView == null) {
            convertedView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
        }
        //Perform your operations over the view here...
    }

}
```

Anyways, I Strongly reccomend you save this list in a db.

Hope it helps :]

Comment: Also, take note that `(convertView == null)` is true only the first time that the element is displayed. All the another times `convertView` will be recycled.

Comment: what do u mean by recycled ?

Comment: now that that's solved i have another question... how do u get a song duration without using any MediaPlayer... ?

Comment: "what do u mean by recycled ?" You are creating the items view each time that is displayed (in the `getView`), if `(convertView != null)` then you don't need inflate it again.

Answer (score 1):

This code solved the problem

```
public class MusicAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
      private LayoutInflater l_Inflater;

      public MusicAdapter(Context c) {
            l_Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
      }

      public int getCount() {
            return count;
      }

      public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
      }

      public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
      }

      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            System.gc();

          String id = null;
          TextView txt_itemName = null;

          if (convertView == null) {

  convertView = l_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, null);


 } 




     txt_itemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
              convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);    
 music_column_index = musiccursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
              musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);
              id = musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
              txt_itemName.setText(id);

          return convertView;


      }
}
```